# Creating function in MySQL version 5.7 through Java

Tags: java, mysql, function

This is my function:

```
    query = "CREATE FUNCTION CheckSex(personID INT, G CHAR) " +
                "RETURNS BIT " +
                "BEGIN " +
                    "DECLARE Flag BIT; " +
                    "SET Flag = 1; " +
                    "If (G NOT IN (SELECT Sex FROM PERSONS WHERE ID = personID)) " +    
                    "THEN SET Flag = 0; " +
                    "RETURN Flag; " + 
                "END"; 
        pState = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pState.executeUpdate();
```

This is the error code:
         check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I have tried putting it into the mysql command line manually and I get an error after DECLARE Flag BIT;, also I have tried to change the delimiter which gave an error.

I have switched to an online compiler for now and this function works fine in MySql 2014 express written as follows

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckSex(@personID AS INT, @G as CHAR)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Flag BIT = 1 
If (@G NOT IN (SELECT Sex FROM PERSONS WHERE ID = @personID))   
    SET @Flag = 0
RETURN @FLAG 
END;
```

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: "2014 Express" refers to a version of Microsoft SQL Server. Whereas 5.7 is a version of MySQL. These are two different software products made by different companies. They have slightly different SQL syntax in some cases. You need to decide which software you are using, and then study the reference documentation for the software you are using. Don't mix them, or use the syntax supported by one software in the other one.

Comment: Hint: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html shows the syntax for the `IF ... THEN ... END IF` statement in MySQL. You're missing the `END IF` part.

Comment: I understand that, I'm not sure where my error in 5.7 is, that is why I wrote it in 2014 Express. I just gave it as an example.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'll try that.